# Problema al ordenar (bubble sort) una lista de elementos 'li' con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, array, canvas

Mi intención es poder ordenar una lista ('ul') con sus elementos ('li'), teniendo como criterio de ordenación su alto ('height'), con el fin de crear un efecto visual en el DOM. A la hora de desordenarlo funciona bien, el problema esta a la hora de ordenarlo, no lo ordena bien aunque, a priori, parece que la comparación entre alturas y la reasignación de la misma funciona bien.
A continuación dejo el código utilizado en JavaScript. Mi intención es crear un 'Array sort Visualizer' básico, o usando 'canvas' con el mismo fin.

```javascript
const marco = document.getElementById("marco");
const pixel = document.getElementById("pixel");
const input_texto = document.getElementById("input_texto");
const btn_text = document.getElementById("btn_texto");
const lista = document.getElementById("lista");
let array = [];

let ventana_w = 500;
let ventana_h = 500;
let bar_w = ventana_w / ventana_h;
let num_bars = ventana_w / bar_w;
let bar_h = ventana_h / num_bars;

for (let i = 0; i < num_bars; i++) {
  array[i] = i;
}

function crearElemento(i) {
  let elemento = document.createElement("li");
  elemento.style.width = bar_w + "px";
  elemento.style.height = array[i] * bar_h + "px";
  elemento.style.left = i * bar_w + "px";
  lista.appendChild(elemento);
}

// inicializo el Array
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  crearElemento(i);
}

const sleepNow = (delay) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delay));

// Desordenar
let elemento, elemento2, rng;
async function shufler() {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    rng = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
    elemento = document.getElementsByTagName("li")[rng];
    elemento2 = document.getElementsByTagName("li")[i];

    let aux = elemento.style.height;
    elemento.style.height = elemento2.style.height;
    elemento2.style.height = aux;

    await sleepNow(1);
  }
}
shufler();

// Bubble sort
let elemento_li = (otroElemento = document.getElementsByTagName("li"));
async function bubble() {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < array.length - 1 - i; j++) {
      if (elemento_li[j].style.height > elemento_li[j + 1].style.height) {
        let aux = elemento_li[j].style.height;
        elemento_li[j].style.height = elemento_li[j + 1].style.height;
        elemento_li[j + 1].style.height = aux;
      }
      await sleepNow(1);
    }
  }
}
bubble();
```

Comment: En el primer for debes poner i = 1 
Y en el segundo j=0;j<(arreglo.length - i)

Comment: @Japv he probado lo que dices y creo que es lo mismo que si i = 0 y en el segundo j = 0 ; j < arreglo.length - 1 - i. De todos modos me da el mismo problema, a la hora de mostrar los cambios en pantalla no se ve como deberia. Gracias de todos modos.

Comment: Te recomiendo que hagas una prueba aparte utilizando un arreglo de números para ir descartando y veas como se ordena este arreglo

Comment: @Japv He seguido tu consejo de hacerlo con un array mas pequeño, y resulta que javascript cuando compara. por ejemplo, "9px" > "99px" daba True, lo cual es falso, resulta que al comparar cadena de caracteres según su valor en ASCII. Gracias por la ayuda y tu consejo, un saludo.